# Google one tap successfull login redirects to myaccount.google.com instead of my site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-signin, omniauth, google-identity

I have integrated the Google one-tap sign-in in my rails app.

It is working fine for some users but for few users after successful sign-in, it redirects them to `myaccount.google.com` instead of my site and after that, if the user goes to my site, they are signed in automatically.

What could be the possible reason?

I followed this guide to integrate one-tap sign-in.
https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid

Comment: Saqib how did you integrate the Sign in with google with rails app, can you please help me ? I have read the docs it's very confusing I'm getting the credentials after user clicks on sign-in-with-google btn. do I need to send the credentials back to server and decode the values ?